# android custom listener/callback with loop

Tags: android, android-intent

I have implemented a callback/listener in my android app as below:

```
public interface class OnListener() {
  public void onReceive();
}

public class CLASSA {
  private OnListener l = new OnListener() {
    @Override
    public void OnReceive() {
      Log.v(TAG, "Received response");
    };
  CLASSB obj = new CLASSB();
  obj.methodA(l);
}

public class CLASSB {
  void methodA(OnListener l) {
    <define a new thread t> {
    loop (<some condition>) {
      l.OnReceive();
    }
    }
    t.start();
  }
```

Now if the loop is running and CLASSA is getting continuous callbacks/responses and obj is set to null while the loop is running, I still keep getting callbacks i.e. I still see "Received response" in my logs. Why? Should I not get some exception? What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Are you running the loop in a different thread or something? how would you set obj to null if the loop is still running?

Comment: Edited CLASSB code to run the loop in different thread.

Comment: Well what exception were you expecting to get? The thread continues to run. Thread will continue to run until it's done basically, even if there's no references to it.

Comment: No. My question is if the loop is running (I'm getting "Received response" in logs for every loop) and I set obj = null, then why do I still see "Received response" printed in my logcat. It should throw some sort of exception. Isn't it?

Comment: No, the thread continues to run, and the listener is alive because there's still a reference to it

Comment: (Edited CLASSA code above). What if I set l = null? Now I'm removing the reference to listener, is it expected to throw exception now? I did that and loop still runs and I keep getting responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this into a runnable Java program - and yes it continues to output "Response Received" forever. The reason is the program still maintains a reference to the ThreadGroup - see this  [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676035/what-will-happen-when-a-java-thread-is-set-to-null) Within that a reference still is maintained to the listener, because it's part of the run() method. What happens outside of the thread is irrelevant.

`class CLASSB
{
    public void methodA(final OnListener l)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    l.OnReceive();
                }
            }
        })
                .start();
    }
}
interface OnListener
{
    public void OnReceive();
}`

public class CLASSA 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         CLASSB obj = new CLASSB();
         OnListener l = new OnListener() {
                @Override
                public void OnReceive() {
                  System.out.println("Received response");
                }
              };
          obj.methodA(l);
          obj = null;
          l = null;
    }
}