# What happen if we want to interrupt the thread by setting the current by substituting equal to null

Tags: java, multithreading

What Would happen if we interrupt a thread by making it's object reference equal to null

does the thread stack vanish or it still completes its whole processing and safely exists from the run method

There real scenario  is 
1.  Read a file (validate file check for duplicate)
2.  Convert the file data to java Beans
3. validate the beans(check for duplicate in the database)
4.  insert the bean in the database(Batch of size 100 is added on by one)

There are about 1000 Similar Batch for a single file to be added to The Database

and all this processing is done in a single task i cannot set a flag of use interrupt because to check flag or interrupt it has to be in while loop in that case the step 1-4 are performed repeatedly  but the step 4 is the last then it should exit from run if i have to manually stop the thread

i want that if interrupt the thread the processing should stop in any of the above step 
if the 600th chunk is added to the database and interrupt in called for the thread 601 should not be added to database

Comment: This is not interrupting the thread btw.

Comment: What do you think? Did you try it?

Comment: it would take you abt 2 min experiment to find out. whats the point of this question?

Comment: i read the same article it states that even if it thread reference is made null is still complete its processing and is also not applicable for garbage collection . Running Thread has always reference to the ThreadGroup [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676035/what-will-happen-when-a-java-thread-is-set-to-null)

Comment: Dear nafas i have a thread running that extract 1 lakh record from the file and insert it into the mysql database i need a functionality to stop the thread in between even though the thread is inter-reputed or thread reference is made null it still complete processing and it create memory leak

Comment: A Thread is an object, and you can't set an object to null.  All you can do is set references to null.

Comment: @user3194123: so you have the answer to your question: setting the thread reference to null doesn't stop the thread. You need to interrupt the thread, as explained in the Thread javadoc, or in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: JB Nizet : i cannot user interrupt method or flag because i want a  thread to perform a single task in his lifetime and stop thread after completion of the task or while executing the task if i have to use a flag or interrupt method it will be in loop and will perform single task multiple times and we have to stop the thread ourself --------   i want to clear thread stack as soon as it stop